# How get Categories of a single tt_news for Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I want to get the categories of a single new but the Typoscript code:

```
page.100.data = GP:tx_ttnews|cat
```

Does not work, the return show `cat = 0` in the page.

I need this value for set it in a list tt_news in its `categorySelection`

Answer (score 2):

Is the category really in the URL? That is not the case for a single news. You only have the news uid and need to do the join yourself.

Try something like that

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news > 0]
lib.categoryTitle = COA
lib.categoryTitle {

  20 = RECORDS
  20 {
    source.data = register:newsCategoryUid
    tables = tt_news_cat
    conf.tt_news_cat = TEXT
    conf.tt_news_cat.field = title
    conf.tt_news_cat.noTrimWrap = || - |
  }

}
```

Comment: Did this work ? and how if the news item belong to different categories ?